# Fastest way to remove a list of words from a file

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to think of a fast and efficient way to delete a list of stop words from a file. Unfortunately I cant figure out a good way to do this.

The only method I have is to compare each word of the file to an array of stop words, comparing the word to every section of the array would be super slow, and considering the size of the file is 31 mb and that is the smallest of seven files to repeat the process for.

Considering the size, every nanosecond counts, so if anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.

EDIT:: To give you guys a better idea of the files, I am sorting Stack overflow questions from 2008 to now, so essentially anything is possible, I am creating a search engine, but step one on that long long path is getting rid of words in questions that have no bearing or importance such "the", "a" etc. Then I have to add the words that are left to an AVL tree and up to me, catalog the location so for example if someone looks for c++ I can go to the tree find the node with c++ and in that node it has, C++ shows up in line 2003 of 2009.txt and 101 of 2012.txt, (for example). Hope the extra detail and final goal helps clear things up

Comment: Put the words to remove in an [`unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set)?

Comment: I am not sure comparing words would be that slow compared to the time taken to read the file. And what else can you do? You have to compare the words to know if they are in the list! Are there a lot of words in the list?

Comment: 31mb is not a large file. Take the brute force approach, see if it is good enough, and if not you have a baseline to measure against when you try and optimize. You say you have to apply this to 7 files. Is that once or many times? If it's once you probably could have written and run the code on all the files in less time than it took to ask this question. :)

Comment: For almost all of your words only the first one or two characters will be compared which is a fast integer operation. As others have said, give it a try.

Comment: How many words are in your list? Is it like < 10 or like 1000?

Comment: I can give my initial thought a try it just seemed that running each word against an array of about 30 words so many times would add up, and @Tas roughly about 4,000,000 before word count on word crashes

Comment: You might also want to constrain the problem a bit.   Are the "file" or the "list of stop words" likely to have repeated words?   Does the order of words in the "file" matter? - for example does it matter if "How now brown cow" is sorted as "brown cow now how"?   What do you mean by "removal" - Would input like "How now brown cow" with a stop word of "brown" end up as "How now cow" or as "How now ***** cow"?  Is it the file on disk that needs to have words removed, or representation of that file in your program memory?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

1. Put the stop words into a hash table, so checking if a word is in the list will take a constant time, i.e. O(1): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table
2. Memory map the file into memory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file
3. In a loop, get next word and check if it is in the hash table.
4. If the word in the hash table, just save the ranges to delete to a list.
5. After all the words has beed checked, just walk through the list of ranges to delete and "compact" the file.
6. Trim and close the memory mapped file to get the results written to disk.

Comment: Thank you for that, thats one half of the problem, but for this section of the project I have to use an AVL tree

Comment: @zavier so use the tree instead of writing the file? The main idea is to use hash table instead of the list, the rest is up to you...